# Access Token not retrieving data from Facebook PHP sdk

Tags: php, facebook, magento

Here's my code to retrieve user's info from Facebook. I am using PHP SDK.

```
    public function indexAction()
    {

        $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
            'app_id' => '934741473308351',
            'app_secret' => 'de001d018a7769eb17eb11300e772a0c',
            'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
            'default_access_token' => isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']) ? $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] : 'APP-ID|APP-SECRET'


        ]);
        try {
            if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
                $response = $fb->get('/me');
                $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
                Mage::log("Email====>Before".$userNode->getFirstName());
                // echo  'Name: ' . $user['first_name'];
                $this->_redirectUrl('/app-new/app/#/myAccount');
                exit;
            }

             //redirect, or do whatever you want
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            //echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            //echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
        $permissions = ['email', 'user_likes']; // optional
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl().'facebook/facebook/authenticate', $permissions);

        echo $loginUrl;

    }

    public function authenticateAction(){
        Mage::log("Authenticate=======");

        $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
            'app_id' => '934741473308351',
            'app_secret' => 'de001d018a7769eb17eb11300e772a0c',
            'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
        ]);

            $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
            try {
                $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
                // When Graph returns an error
                echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                exit;
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
                // When validation fails or other local issues
                echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                exit;
            }
            if (isset($accessToken)) {
                // Logged in!

                Mage::log("Access Token=================>".(string) $accessToken);

                $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one

                $fb->setDefaultAccessToken((string) $accessToken);
                $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

                try {
                    $response = $fb->get('/me');
                    $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
                    Mage::log("Email====>Before".$userNode->getFirstName());
                    $customer = $this->checkIfUserExists($userNode);
                    $this->_redirectUrl('/app-new/app/#/myAccount');
                    exit;
                } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
                    // When Graph returns an error
                    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                    exit;
                } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
                    // When validation fails or other local issues
                    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                    exit;
                }
            }


    }
```

I got the result first, but I am not getting result after that. Is it due to access taken or something else. What am I doing wrong here

Comment: please be more detailed, your question is quite unclear right now. what result do you get, and when exactly? after what do you get no result. what exactly do you want to get?

Comment: I want to get email id, first name, last name and profile picture. I am getting null when I use $userNode->getEmail()

Comment: answered. please consider using google or the stackoverflow search next time, this question has been asked a lot of times already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a new feature of v2.4 of the Graph API, it´s called "Declarative Fields". You now have to add a `field` parameter to specify the fields you want to get, else you will only get `id` and `name`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Also, make sure your login works correctly and you get asked for the `email` permission when you authorize your App.